# How to remove style attribute only with DOMXPATH?

Tags: php, xpath, php-5.3, domxpath

I use DOMXPATH to remove **all** `attributes` from the `p` tag and it works fine,

```
// Loop all p.
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( "p" ) as $p )
{
    // Loop all attributes in p.
    foreach( $p->attributes as $attrib )
    {
          // Remove all attribute   from p. 
          $p->removeAttributeNode( $attrib );
    }

}
```

And now I want to remove **style** `attribute` only from the p tag.

```
// Loop all p.
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( "p" ) as $p )
{
    // Loop all attributes in p.
    foreach( $p->attributes as $attrib )
    {
          // Remove only the style attribute
      $p->removeAttributeNode( $p->getAttributeNode( "style" ) );
    }

}
```

But I have this error in return,

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   DOMElement::removeAttributeNode() must be an instance of DOMAttr,
>   boolean given..

How can I remove **style** `attribute` only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace this

```
// Loop all attributes in p.
foreach( $p->attributes as $attrib )
{
      // Remove only the style attribute
  $p->removeAttributeNode( $p->getAttributeNode( "style" ) );
}
```

with something like this:

```
// fetch style node
$sNode = $p->getAttributeNode( "style" )
// only procede, if $p actually has a style node
if ($sNode) {
  $p->removeAttributeNode( $sNode );
}
```

(not tested, sorry, i don't have a server installed here)